# SQL statement to replace final part of an URL

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Replace in a `videos` table with a column `URL` with many different URL types.
I use MariaDB 10.3

```
https://google.com/questions/ask?963
https://google.com/embed/57=66.88.028.10/i/03/077fsdf
https://google.com/top57=66.88.028.10/i/03/077
https://video.net/emb.html?asdeen45dr57=66.88.028.10/i/03/07776/asdeen45dr57
https://video.net/fomdfk5f7s1f.html
https://video.net/emb.html?qsfeen4gttv1=54.47.158.810/i/11/00036/qsfeen4gttv1
```

I need to delete part of a specific URL (delete all after `=`)
and replace with .html

from

```
https://video.net/emb.html?asdeen45dr57=66.88.028.10/i/03/07776/asdeen45dr57
```

to

```
https://video.net/emb.html?asdeen45dr57.html
```

In this case, will replace

```
=66.88.028.10/i/03/07776/asdeen45dr57
```

with

```
.html
```

Please note, the URL part, after the `=` sign, are different for each URL.

Comment: What version of mysql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running MySql 8.0 or later you can use `regexp_replace`

```
UPDATE videos
SET url = REGEXP_REPLACE(url, '=.*$', '.html')
WHERE url LIKE 'https://video.net%'
```

Without regular expression this will work (also fine for MySql 5.*)

```
UPDATE videos 
SET url = CONCAT(SUBSTR(url, 1, INSTR(url, '=') - 1), '.html')
WHERE url LIKE 'https://video.net%'
```

Comment: but only need to remplace if `URL` is like `video.net/emb.html?`

Comment: Well you can simply add that as a WHERE condition `url LIKE 'https://video.net/emb.html?%'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
update t
    set url = concat(substring_index(url, '=', 1), '.html')
    where url like '%-%'
```